# Get Comments History from Connect Custom Configuration payload

Tags: docusignapi, docusignconnect

How can I get the comments history as pdf from custom configuration ?

[image]

[image]

From DocuSign request payload we have the following property

```
public List<EnvelopeDocument> envelopeDocuments { get; set; }
```

but the comments history pdf is not in this list.

The Certificate of Completion (summary) is included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DocuSign Connect doesn't support this.

You will have to make a separate API call to obtain the PDF of the Comments.

https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/comments/get/